# Apex Test Class for very simple apex trigger

Tags: apex, unit-test

I have just created my first very simple apex trigger and it works. However it fails to deploy because it covers 0% code and I have discovered that i need a test class.

The trigger should insert the account of the respective contact. I need it to update a lot of older records. I tried also with process builder, but that fails in data loader so apex was my only choice. I have created a formula field with the account ID to make it work.

Any idea how my test class should look like? My code is:

```
trigger insAccAftale  on Aftaler__c (before insert, before update){

for (Aftaler__c a: Trigger.new)
{
    if(a.Account__c == null){
        a.Account__c = a.AccountID__c;        
    }
}
}
```

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: See e.g. [Testing Apex Triggers](https://developer.salesforce.com/trailhead/apex_testing/apex_testing_triggers).

Comment: You would do it with a WFR and Field Update, then simply update the records using data loader. No need for the trigger

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Keith suggested go through Developer guides, they are your best friend when it comes to salesforce development. 
I am giving you sample code which you need to modify as per your org schema. I am explaining here in very layman terms.

So when writing a test, we basically test the functionality of code.
In case of trigger, we insert test data and verify whether we get the correct results or not.

In your scenario we need to insert a test account record because we gonna need account id.

Next, we have to insert test Aftaler__c record. When this record will be inserted your trigger will be invoked.

In system.assert we will be checking whether the trigger worked correctly or not

```
@isTest
private class insAccAftale {

    private static testMethod void insAccAftaleTest1() {
        Account acc = new Account();
        acc.name='Test Account';
        //add other required fields
        insert acc;
        Aftaler__c a= new Aftaler__c();
        a.name= 'test';
        //add required fields
        a.AccountID__c=acc.id;
        //checking whether we got expected results or not 
        System.assert(a.Account__c, acc.id);
    }

}
```